# Wrap unix sockets to make them HTTP compatible

Tags: nginx, http, socket

I want to use [signald](https://git.callpipe.com/finn/signald) via web. signald is an application that provides a unix socket and communicates in JSON.

I can use nginx to connect to the unix socket via HTTP(S). But signald does not understand HTTP, only pure JSON. It produces errors like the following:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'GET': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"GET / HTTP/1.0"; line: 1, column: 4]`

Is there a way to send JSON to my web-forwarded unix socket, just like any API that is served by a web server? I imagine something like nginx <-> http wrapper <-> unix socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time, but I found a solution. Basically, you have to use Lua to get the request body, send it to a unix socket, read the line and send it back as server response. Use nginx with lua like this:

First install `nginx-extras`

Load modules ndk_http_module and ngx_http_lua_module (*in this order*) in nginx.conf like this:

```
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
```

This is the `location` block for your lua-enhanced connection to the unix socket. It will send the request data to the unix socket and read by using [tcpsocket:receive()](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lua_Nginx_API/#tcpsockreceive). It will [say()](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lua_Nginx_API/#ngxsay) the line as response.

```
    location / {
        content_by_lua_block {
            ngx.req.read_body()
            local body_data = ngx.req.get_body_data()

            local sock = ngx.socket.tcp()
            local ok, err = sock:connect("unix:/var/run/signald/signald.sock")

            local bytes = sock:send(body_data)

            local line, err, part = sock:receive()
            if line then
                ngx.say(line)
            end

            ok, err = sock:close()
        }
    }
```

Test it with a curl call like this (you don't have to care about `Content-Type` or method):

```
curl -d '{"type":"version"}' https://example.com:1234
```